error on my chrome web store related to extensions button of add being faded in my chrome book
I have a problem in my chrome web store whenever i enter the store and click any extension the button that shown add this in other chrome books mine is faded i can't even click to download any extension and there's also error to update my OS when its already updated like when i ask my system for update it always shows updated I have tried shutting down down my book and restarting and those youtube videos but still can't find any helpful materials to help me

Is your Chromebook managed by an organization (school, work, etc)?

No it's my personal one

Has it ever worked before?  Have you enabled Google Play Store and accepted the terms and agreements?  You can find that under Settings | Google Play Store.

It has never worked before and yeah i have accepted the terms of google play store

While it is your personal one now, where did it come from? Did is belong to an org previously or did you purchase it yourself new?

I just newly purchased it
